# Use EJS template to inside ngView with Angular and SailsJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sails.js, ejs

I use Angular with SailsJs without problem.

To take advantage of i18n with Sails, I would like use EJS template (http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/internationalization).
But with ngView directive, to generate my content, Angular show the variables' tag instead of interpret them.

My layout :
*homepage.ejs*

```
<h4><%= __('Augustodunum') %></h4> // Works
<div class="view-animate-container">
  <div data-ng-view class="view-animate"></div>
</div>
```

My partial template (render with ngView directive of Angular) :
*/templates/welcome.ejs*

```
<div>
    <%= __('Ostum') %> // Doesn't work
</div>
```

My routing Angular :
*app.js*

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/templates/welcome.ejs',
            controller: 'WelcomeController',
            activetab: 'welcome'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/',
            caseInsensitiveMatch: true
        })
    }]);
```

My routing Sails :
*routes.js*

```
 '/': {
    view: 'homepage'
  }
```

How do you make Angular (via ngView) interpret EJS please ?

Comment: You would need routes that compile those on server rather than send raw ejs file...or use an angular `i18` module

Comment: Hum.. You think the best is to use the Angular's i18n or server-side? I don't know which is more logical, but to use the Angular's i18n force to manage translations in multiple files